iOS App crash after Flutter upgrade - perhaps related to Accessibility / XML fetch through Appium
seeing an iOS app crash on Flutter versions > 3.10.5 . The App doesn't crash in standalone use mode, but crashes when XML is fetched for few screens, using an automation platform. The no-code automation platform uses Appium libraries to fetch XML of the App screens, so it can record and playback scenarios.
The stack trace (attached and below) entry point mentions UIAccessibilty, so perhaps theres a link to Accessibility. We are wondering if something changed with XML checking post Flutter 3.10.5. Would anyone know of a way to run an APp through an XML checker, to see if there is faulty XML on the screens causing the issue?
Please reply if you have come across something similar or have suggestions to debug.
crash log:

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_MAPERR at 0x10ca8
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00000001af8cc8ac objc_msgSend + 172
1   UIAccessibility                      0x00000001d1fa96d0 -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityFindAncestor:startWithSelf:findTopmostAncestor:] + 132
2   UIKit                                0x000000024d6a30d8 0x24d563000 + 1310936
3   UIKit                                0x000000024d6a08a4 0x24d563000 + 1300644

The app flows worked fine on Flutter versions 3.10.5 and below.
